# Angular variable into routerLink

Tags: angular, routerlink

I'm trying to pass an id in my routerLink, how could I concatenate it?

`<a routerLink="['/details', {{data.id}}]"> </a> doesnt work.`

Do you have solutions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess you have tried to put code inside post? It's not showing. Update it please.

Comment: Code please..and concatenate id with what? path?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put it between quotes

Comment: Remove the curly brackets (`{{ }}`) in what you have now. You just need `data.id` after the route name. That *should* work.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There you go.

```html
<a [routerLink]="['/details', data.id]"> Link </a>
```

Comment: Technically this works but the recommended way is to pass it as the second argument. Please take a look at Aragom's answer.

Answer (score 7):

Parameters go as second item in the array syntax to  router link, like this:

```
[routerLink]="['/details', data.id]
```

Read more [here](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink#description)

Answer (score 1):

Similar to above, but you can also do this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/details' + data.id]"> Link </a>
```