# Pass variable to Angular routerLink

Tags: angular, angular-routing

My current URL:

`http://localhost:4200/app/projects/ABC1/dashboards/5f6cc1e632acae2b16160123`

What I want to do is that when I click on a button, that the URL gets changed to
`http://localhost:4200/app/projects/ABC1/dashboards/new`

I am trying it with `routerLink`

```
<button [routerLink]="['./projects/' + projectId + '/dashboards/new']">
```

but how can I replace `projectId` with the variable that I have in that place?

I also tried to pass a function to routerLink which returns the following

```
public routeToCreateDashboard = (projectId: string): string => {
    return `./projects/${projectId}/dashboards/new`;
  };
```

but this doesnt work too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular variable into routerLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53523472/angular-variable-into-routerlink)

Comment: @Roy Unfortunately not because I need to have the variable in my URL and not passed as param.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a [stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com)? I don't see the problem here. And yes, you can absolutely have a `(click)` and `routerLink` on the same element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For String Interpolation this might help you:

```
// You can use String Interpolation this way

routerLink="/update/{{obj.id}}"
```

for add event when route changed you can use router event:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {NavigationEnd, Router, RouterEvent} from '@angular/router';
import {filter, map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RouteEventService {
  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  subscribeToRouterEventUrl(): Observable<string> {
    return this.router.events
      .subscribe(  (event: RouterEvent) => {
                     if(event instanceof NavigationStart){

                     // console.log('Navigation Start', this.router.url);
                     }
          }

      );
  }
}
```